# Asp directory listing unfolding

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I'm using http://www.brainjar.com/asp/dirlist/ ( example: http://www.brainjar.com/asp/dirlist/demo.asp ) to list a directory we use to upload some things clients need.

I would like to make it list the folders only and opening them with a click instead of showing everything off.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS in your page:

```
ul ul {
    display:none;
}
```

And add jQuery to your page and this script:

```
$(function(){
   $('ul li b').on('click', function(){
      $(this).next('ul').toggle()        
   })
})
```

Comment: I need a way to get the next UL and their parents that are on the same dom node, can you help me with that ?

Comment: "get" them? And do what?

Comment: toggle the visibility not only on the next('ul') but also their sibling ul's because it goes like this when displaying: http://pastebin.com/FrMVARsj

Comment: nope, it does not work. heres the link to the actual thing praticsistemas.com.br/lista2.asp

Comment: $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle()   did it for me. Thanks Diodeus.